# Creating an admin panel for Django site

Tags: python, django

What I would like to have is an admin panel that I create where only users with permissions set to "admin" in the `UserLevel` model can edit certain aspects of the website. However, while I think I have everything coded out properly it isn't working. The way I'm trying to implement this already work on the main content section of my site. My best guess is that since I'm trying to cross-use views between apps something got mixed up, although that may be wrong. Also please keep in mind that while I definitely started with clean code which emulated the code from the working parts of the site this code may not so clean because I have been playing around with it so much that I'm just flat out confused... so any help would be much appreciated.

To be clear, there's no error with the site which is why I think the code is written correctly. However, I made a test widget which is not displaying on the home page at all (it's supposed to), nor will it display on the admin panel page I setup (which is supposed to display any widgets there may be), and I can't get the form for adding a new widget to display on the admin panel page either (it gives me a button to go to another page that has the form on it).

Project urls.py:

```
"""colors URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
from colorsets import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
    url(r'^adminpanel/',include('adminpanel.urls',namespace='adminpanel')),
]
```

Adminpanel app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from adminpanel import views

app_name = 'adminpanel'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^settings/',views.SettingsListView.as_view(),name='settings'),
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreateWidgetView.as_view(),name='create-widget'),
    url(r'^delete/$',views.DeleteWidget.as_view(),name='delete-widgets'),
]
```

Adminpanel app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from adminpanel.forms import WidgetForm
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
class CreateWidgetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = WidgetForm
    model = Widget

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class SettingsListView(ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = WidgetForm
    model = Widget

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_query(self):
        return Widget.object.filter(order_by('widget_order'))

class DeleteWidget(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Widget
    select_related = ('Widget',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_query()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Colorsets app views.py (Where I started mixing things):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from colorsets.forms import ColorForm
from colorsets import models
from colorsets.models import ColorSet
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
#def index(request):
#   return render(request,'index.html')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ColorSet
    model = Widget

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ColorSet.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        return Widget.objects.filter(order_by('widget_order'))

class CreateColorSetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ColorForm
    model = ColorSet

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = models.ColorSet
    select_related = ('user',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Adminpanel app models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    widget_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

widget_list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        {% for widget in widget_list %}
            <p>{{ widget.body }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

_post.html:

```
<div class="post media">
    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>{{ colorset.user.username }}</strong>

        <div class="media-footer">
            {% if user.is_authenticated and UserLevels.access_level == 'admin' %}
                <a href="{% url 'colorsets:delete' pk=colorset.pk %}" title="delete" class="btn btn-simple">
                    Delete
                </a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

widget_form.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="colorset-base">
        <h2>Create new widget</h2>
        <form id="postForm" action="{% url 'adminpanel:create-widget' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-large">Add Widget</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Settings:</h2>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

widget_confirm_delete.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this widget?</h3>

    <div class="posts">
        {% include "adminpanel/_post.html" with post=object hide_delete=True %}
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-large" />
        <a class="btn btn-simple btn-large" href="{% url 'adminpanel/settings'%}">Cancel</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I know not everything is being used by things but this is everything I have.

Comment: What is the error, or what is not working ?

Comment: So there's no error with the site which is how I know the code is written fine. however, I made a test widget which is not displaying on the home page at all, nor will it display on the admin panel page I setup, and I can't get the form for adding a new widget to display on the admin panel page either.

Comment: Why you don't use the default admin pannel?
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: @Mattia In this particular case I could, however I want to be able to implement this because in future projects I may not want all my users to be able to interact and change everything on my site and I may also want to display stuff to them in a different way than is done via Django admin. This is more so just for learning purposes so I can have the ability to do it.